# tomcat security constraints

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, security-constraint

How do you negate a security constraint in tomcat?

Basically, I have one security constraint defined which setup up basic authentication for the entire context.

How can I exclude one file, for example, /public-available.html from this? So I have authentication setup for everything, except this one resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this: http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-web-security
In case you face any problem, let me know.

It will be much easier to manage your security constraint if you put files with different access in different folder/hierarchy. ex: **/public**/public-available.html, **/restricted**/xyz.html